# Shiro in Dropwizard keeps redirecting me to the login page

Tags: authentication, shiro, dropwizard

I'm integrating Shiro into my dropwizard webapp. I've gotten to the point that

- shiro recognizes resources that need authentication, and sends me to the login page (/auth/login)
- shiro alerts me if a login fails due to the wrong password (/auth/login?loginFailed=true)
- shiro only redirects if I try to access a protected resource (like /admin/**)
- shiro redirects to a defined page upon success

However, shiro is always sending me to the login page if I try to access a protected resource, regardless of whether I've logged in or not. I believe the login is working; I also believe shiro isn't honoring whether I've been logged in or not.

my shiro.ini:

```
[main]
# some other stuff
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /auth/login

# NOTE: URLs are evaluated in order, and the first matching pattern is accepted.
[urls]
/static/** = noSessionCreation, anon
/auth/** = authc
/admin/** = authc
/** = anon
```

Also of note: I'm getting an error that says

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0 - - [10/Oct/2013:18:23:54 +0000] "GET /auth/login;JSESSIONID=65e06b39-30e5-45dd-85f9-b2a1c29fc3af HTTP/1.1" 200 739 4 4
WARN  [2013-10-10 18:24:08,485] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent:
A servlet request, to the URI http://blah:8080/auth/login, contains form
parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet
or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using
@FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other
means will not work as expected.
```

and each visit to /admin results in an error 302. I don't know what else is relevant to answer this problem. I've explored several other "Shiro keeps redirecting me to login" questions but most refer directly to Jetty with web.xmls, which Dropwizard doesn't use, nor do I know what filters are being applied. My coworker has used the same method to get shiro working with his dropwizard project.

How does shiro authenticate a user before deciding whether to send him to the login page?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. Here's more of the shiro.ini, specifically the session management part:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
# NOTE: The session ID cookie seems to be required in order for authentication to work as intended.
# If the presence of cookies is a deal-breaker, further investigation will be required.
# Here we enable the Secure attribute (serve over SSL only) for this cookie;
# the HttpOnly attribute (not accessible by JavaScript) is enabled by default.
#sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.secure = true
# enabled Ehcache following advice from Shiro docs
sessionDAO = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO
sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO
# can optionally add session listeners here if actions need to be performed on session start/stop/expiration
# sessionManager.sessionListeners = $listener_1, $listener_2, ...
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

I've commented the sessionIdCookie.secure (and will remove it in a moment.) Turns out that without ssl enabled, cookies aren't stored when that variable is set to true. This explains the JSESSIONID query param in the url bar, but also why, after authenticating, it forgot about me immediately and decided I needed to log in again.